How do batches in Hugging Face transformers internally work?
While using hugging face transformers, when calling the .generate, how are the input prombt internally executed? and how does batch size make a difference? For instance, input dimension (1,128) vs (10, 128).
My assumption is that it's parallelized and not serialized but even if it is, are batches parallelized independently or do threads internally work for matmul in random order for any random batch?
I am looking to understand how threads internally work, how the work is divided and anything else in this direction.
I am unable to find any documentation on it online, so if you could even point me to some resource, I'll be grateful.
Thanks.

https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/src/transformers/generation/utils.py#L1906

It's a 5000 line of code, can you tell me an optimized approach of how to navigate through such codes to find what I want? Or is the normal approach of just going through all relevant function is what everyone does?

I can't speak for everyone but this is what I do: When there is no document explaining what I am looking for, I go and read the code, If its complicated I try to find the section of the code relevant to my problem and focus on that section.  If I fail to understand or cannot find what I am looking for in a reasonable time, I try to ask to the authors and other users of the code. It helps if the project/code has active community.
Docs for hugging face trannsformers: https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/quicktour
Discord for hugging face: https://discord.com/invite/JfAtkvEtRb
